# Stripes in MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, subclass, mkannotationview, mapkit

In an app we made we make use of a subclassed MKAnnotationView. We add

```
PLCalloutButton* rightButton = [PLCalloutButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
rightButton.tag = PLTagDetailPin;
self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

and

```
PLFavoriteButton* favoriteButton = [PLFavoriteButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
favoriteButton.zoneInfo = zoneInfo;
self.leftCalloutAccessoryView = favoriteButton;
```

and that is about all that happens in this subclass.

When the annotation is tapped the view is presented as expected but sometimes a strange stripe appears as if the stretching is not done properly. As seen below part of the background is missing and sometimes this stripe of the background is somewhere else in the annotationview (so we also have a dark stripe).

How can I solve this?

[image: stripe in MKAnnotationView]

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the problem on a scaled back or simplified implementation of you program? Does it occur with any particular version of iOS or on any particular type of device? Does it occur in both the simulator and on the device? What happens if the view is rotated and the screen is redrawn?

Comment: All iOS versions and all devices. This particular app is portrait only. It doesn't happen to all annotations, only some.

Comment: Does it also happen when you are using a standard UIButton?

Comment: Is your background image custom or the default one?